# Show suggested price in product view

Tags: magento-1.9, special-price

I have the code below for the wholesale customers (they see msrp)
I want to show below this: **Suggested price: (special price) for your customers**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<?php   if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):  ?>
    <?php $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); ?> 
    <?php if($groupId == '2'): ?>
        <?php $_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true) ?>
        <?php if($_product->getMsrp()): ?>
            <div class="price-box">     
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
                        <?php echo $_msrpPrice; ?>  <span style="font-size: 10pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;excl. VAT </span>
                    </span>
                </p>    
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>  
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this just **set Group price in Product for that Group**

[image]

Comment: It is impossible, the prices come up from a bridge and there thousands of them!

Comment: You can write script to update the Group price as special price and according to me this will be best way because if you show special price for group of customer but on add to cart it will added with final price of product @CostasSaloubardos